# Socket Timeout at runtime

Tags: c#, sockets

Hey guys I am new at the subject of Sockets
and I really need you help.
I am doing system of server and clients (like chat)
but something diffrent, I am doing it with Windows Form Application
in my server : I have list of sockets of all pepole that connect to the server, that already get acception from the server. 
And I wanna to do a Timer that every X seconds it will runs on my List and check if the person is still connection I mean in that , that the person still connect on the internet and still can get packages and if not to remove him from the list. 
someone can help me in c# how do it??

now at the server if someone is Exit the program Or if the internet is logout how i can check if the Client is out
and if yes so Close his connection?
i Read about TimeOut but how use it??? if it usfull?

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Socket sck;
        static List<Socket> acc;
        static List<Thread> thr;
        //List<UserAt> thr;
        static int port = 9000;
        static IPAddress ip;
        static Thread NewCon;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            acc = new List<Socket>();
            //thr = new List<UserAt>();
            thr = new List<Thread>();
            NewCon = new Thread(getNewConnection);

            //Console.WriteLine("please enter your host port ");
            string inputPort = "9000";
            try
            {
                port = Convert.ToInt32(inputPort);
            }
            catch
            {
                port = 9000;
            }

            ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));
            sck.Listen(0);
            NewCon.Start();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get new connection from client
        /// </summary>
        public void getNewConnection()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                acc.Add(sck.Accept());
                var t = new Thread(() => ReciveMessage(acc.Count-1));
                t.Start();
                thr.Add(t);

              /*  UserAt a = new UserAt();
                a.index = acc.Count - 1;
                a.thread = new Thread(() => ReciveMessage(a.index));
                a.thread.Start();
                thr.Add(a);
               * */
            }
        }


        public void ReciveMessage(int index)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    byte[] Buffer = new byte[255];

                    int rec = acc[index].Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0);
                    Array.Resize(ref Buffer, rec);
                    //MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
                    SetText(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
                }
                catch
                {
                   // thr[index].thread.Abort();
                    /*thr.RemoveAt(index);
                    for (int i = index+1; i < thr.Count;i++ )
                    {
                        thr[i].index -= 1;
                    }*/
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.listBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }

        public string getIp()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "?";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return localIP;

        }
    }
}
```

Client

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Client
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string name = "";
        static int port = 9000;
        static IPAddress ip;
        static Socket sck;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public void ReciveMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[255];
                int rec = sck.Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, 0);
                Array.Resize(ref Buffer, rec);
                SetText(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
                //MyChat.Items.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer));
            }
        }

        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.MyChat.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyChat.Items.Add(text);
            }
        }


        private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            name = UserName.Text;

            ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            string inputPort = "9000";
            try
            {
                port = Convert.ToInt32(inputPort);
            }
            catch
            {
                port = 9000;
            }

            try
            {
                sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sck.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, port));

                ReciveMes.Enabled = true;
                byte[] conmsg = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<" + name + ">" + " connected");
                sck.Send(conmsg, 0, conmsg.Length, 0);

                SendToServer.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("חיבור נכשל");
            }



        }

        private void SendToServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<" + name + ">" + MyMessage.Text);
            sck.Send(sdata, sdata.Length, 0);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(SendToServer.Enabled)
            {
                byte[] sdata = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<" + name + ">" + "Is Quit");
                sck.Send(sdata, sdata.Length, 0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a particular problem you couldn't solve by searching on the web?

Comment: yes i already read about socket timeout but i dont know how to use it for every people here i will edit and post my chat for now

Comment: What did you read about "socket timeout"? Did you try setting the `ReceiveTimeout` property on the `Socket` instance for the accepted socket for each client? What did you try? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please be very specific.

Comment: @PeterDuniho hii there.
i wanna to do like every 5 second send from the server package for each client that connect and if he not response close his connections

Comment: What did you try? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please be very specific.